# Learning basics about objects

Tags: java

```
public class Vector {
    private final double deltaX,deltaY;

    public Vector(double deltaX, double deltaY) {
        this.deltaX = deltaX;
        this.deltaY = deltaY;

    public Vector plus(Vector(a, b)){
        return new Vector(this.deltaX+a,this.deltaY+b);
    }
```

why does this not work when I am trying to create a method to add a new vector to my existing one?
i am defining deltaX as the horizontal component and deltaY as the vertical.

Comment: Java does not support value decomposition. Each parameter must be taken in as a single object/value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the correct syntax. Your method should be:

```
public Vector plus(Vector other) {
    return new Vector(this.deltaX + other.deltaX, this.deltaY + other.deltaY);
}
```

That way, somebody can pass Vector instances into the method.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
public Vector plus(Vector v) {
    return new Vector(this.deltaX + v.getDeltaX(),
                      this.deltaY + v.getDeltaY());
}
```

Where you define those getter methods. Alternately, make `deltaX` and `deltaY` public and access them directly from `v`.